# How can I add simple text under an image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a text under every image of an album. so I've added 6 photos side by side with float left. I know that the img tag is an inline-block of default so I put a div with class text with text inside and in the CSS I assigned it "display: block" in this way I thought I would make it appear under the image .. why this does not happen? I tried also to assign to the div text... position absolute and to the container position relative but this only works for the first image ...

```css
  .conteiner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.box {
  background-image: url('xxx.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: calc(100% / 6 - 20px);
  height: 15vh;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  background-position: center;
}

.clearfix {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  .text {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="conteiner clearfix">

  <div class="box">

  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Recenti
  </div>

  <div class="box">

  </div>

  <div class="box">

  </div>

  <div class="box">

  </div>

  <div class="box">

  </div>

  <div class="box">

  </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNeza.png) that's what I have

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7pVB.png) and that's what I want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much simpler to use Grid or Flexbox to get such a layout. No need for float and clear.

Using Grid:

```
.container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
   width: 100%;
   height: 50vh;
   margin-top: 50px;
   padding: 20px;
}
```

Then simply place the 6 images first to fill up the first row and the 6 texts second to fill up a second row.

```
       <div class="container">

          <div class="box">

          </div>

          <div class="box">

          </div>

          <div class="box">

          </div>

          <div class="box">

          </div>

          <div class="box">

          </div>

          <div class="box">

          </div>
        <div class="text">
           Recenti
        </div>
        <div class="text">
           Recenti
        </div>
        <div class="text">
           Recenti
        </div>
        <div class="text">
           Recenti
        </div>
        <div class="text">
           Recenti
        </div>
        <div class="text">
           Recenti
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also, the content of the grid will be sized to fill the grid area so you may not have to explicitly size the box.

```
.box{
  background-image: url('xxx.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15vh;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

https://codepen.io/the-wrong-guy/pen/xxZzBwR

```
.box {
  display: grid;
}
```